# Class SMTP not found in phpmailer

Tags: php, email, gmail

I am having this problem for my php mailer function. I tried changing the required file but still its the same. Can anyone help me with this error.

This is my phpmailer code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "testnoreply@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "test";
$mail->SetFrom("testnoreply@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Membership expire notice";
$mail->Body = "Dear ICONIS member your membership is going to expire please renew it";
$mail->AddAddress($em);

if (!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " .$mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Mail has been sent";
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the library?

Comment: `require_once("PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");`

Comment: You should include its autoloader instead `require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';` as shown in the example at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: its still the same..

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have both the class.phpmailer.php AND the class.smtp.php in your folder?

Try including class.smtp.php before including class.phpmailer.php, as the following:

```
<?php
include 'class.smtp.php';
include 'class.phpmailer.php';
// your code goes here
```

Then tell if you got some error.

Answer (score 0):

just download all files, extract the files into a folder and include PHPMailerAutoload.php from the folder.

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */
//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

/*======================================*/
/*======================================*/
require 'YOURFOLDERNAME/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
/*======================================*/
/*======================================*/


//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

instead of

```
require 'class.phpmailer.class.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```